# Baby's drink, mathematician's think$\ $

Tags: riddle, word

There are two people I must absolutely thank. @Mithrandir made this a rhyme in the first place, and @Rubio guided and helped me in making this puzzle a lot.

---

> *In chemistry, this is a thing.
>
>   It makes the mathematicians sing.
>
>   A baby may know it as well
>
>   but not the same way, you can tell.*
>
> *For the baby likes to think of drinks
>
>   and mathematicians prefer the thought of thinks.
>
>   Engineers use them, yes they do
>
>   but not for trains, no no to you.*
>
> *Einstein used an E and C
>
>   the baby prefers the milk, you see.
>
>   And in yet another way
>
>   your mother used it, in a separate way.*
>
> *In the kitchen, as you may find
>
>   but not the ones that stretch your mind.*

**What am I?**

Comment: Flows better than some of the past ones. But you can't really rhyme way with way.

Comment: I've downvoted since it was taken entirely from Mithrandir in a private conversation without permission. That's... not a thing you should do.

Comment: Wait, so who actually wrote the riddle?  And why did you post both it and  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53994/simply-a-relationship-of-symbols?

Comment: Please don't make minor edits to bump your riddles.

Comment: @Deusovi Absolutely not. I didn't. Mithrandir wanted to keep the NO, that's why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> Formula?

In chemistry, this is a thing.

> Refers to a chemical formula, with elements and such.

It makes the mathematicians sing.

> Mathematical formulas for equations!

A baby may know it as well /
but not the same way, you can tell.

> There are bottle formulas for feeding to babies.

For the baby likes to think of drinks /
and mathematicians prefer the thought of thinks.

> Of course, baby formula and equation formulas are quite different--one is a drink, and the other is something you think up.

Engineers use them, yes they do /
but not for trains, no to you.

> Engineers do use formulas to find values, but train engineer is the term for people who handle/drive trains, so they don't use formulas to derive answers to their particular problems. (Thanks to @Mithrandir for the tip on this one!)

Einstein used an E and C

> Referring to E = mc^2

the baby prefers the milk, you see. /
And in yet another way /
your mother used it, in a separate way.

> Though babies may prefer their mothers' milk, mothers often use formula instead.

In the kitchen, as you may find /
but not the ones that stretch your mind.

> You might find baby formula in the kitchen, but probably not a mathematical formula.

And of course, the title "Baby's drink, mathematician's think" refers to

> The difference between the mix for feeding to infants, and the formulas that mathematicians find and prove.

Comment: try heading to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_engineer) about the trains

Comment: wow, formula actually makes much more sense, but I was still typing mine up when you posted it, haha

Comment: @Mithrandir Ah, thanks. Didn't know about that usage of the word!

Comment: @MMAdams I actually quite like your answer. It's very clever and certainly made me smile. :)

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Avogadro's number: 6.022 x 10^23 ?

In chemistry, this is a thing.
It makes the mathematicians sing.

> Avogadro's number is often used in chemistry, and written in scientific notation, which is mathematical.

A baby may know it as well
but not the same way, you can tell.

> Baby food is often made of mushy vegetables like Avocados, which to a baby sounds almost the same as Avogadro.

For the baby likes to think of drinks
and mathematicians prefer the thought of thinks.

> Babies don't typically think about much other than food.

Engineers use them, yes they do
but not for trains, no to you.

> Engineers may sometimes need to use moles to calculate densities of things maybe? Not for big projects like trains probably.

Einstein used an E and C
the baby prefers the milk, you see.

> Einstein used the speed of light constant, c, where Avogadro's constant is usually Na.

And in yet another way
your mother used it, in a separate way.

> There's the 'separate way' thing again, talking about Avocados, or perhaps mole, which is just a sauce.

In the kitchen, as you may find
but not the ones that stretch your mind.

> You use Avocados and Mole in the kitchen, but not Moles (well, technically those are everywhere too, but we don't count them all the time)