# Simply a relationship of symbols

Tags: riddle, word

> Mathematicians love me
>   Chemistry students study me
>   Even lovers of language use me.
>   I am
>   a relationship built of symbols,
>   a procedure or a hard-and-fast rule,
>   Or the things something’s made of,
>   feeding newborns when the mother’s not able.

**What am I?**

Comment: isn't this exactly the same as https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53992/babys-drink-mathematicians-think?

Comment: This may be a duplicate but why would you post another riddle with the same solution and pretty similar clues anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a...

> FORMULA

*Mathematicians love me*

> Refers to a [mathematical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula) or equation.

*Chemistry students study me*

> Refers to a [chemical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_formula) that denotes chemical composition.

*Even lovers of language use me.*

> Maybe refers to [formulaic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulaic_language) in writing, or a formula in formal language in mathematics.

*I am a relationship built of symbols, a procedure or a hard-and-fast rule,*

> Definition of a mathematical formula. Same meaning as the puzzle title.

*Or the things something’s made of,*

> Definition of a chemical formula

*feeding newborns when the mother’s not able.*

> Refers to [infant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infant_formula), which is used for feeding young infants.