# I apologise to the answer

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

> Their head sounds like a myth, with an eye for why
>   Endless, it says to meet but briefly so,
>   standing for the very famous MA institute.
>
> Then comes the first name of another puzzler, all too familiar
>   Named who is after the prime of a time wheel with
>   a Norse god at his feet, starting six places away.
>
> At last, anger or annoy without end—
>   its birth half the death and equally four sided
>   of any trio’s total member number.

#### I apologise to that person. But who are they?

*Bonus: Find out why.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It's [Mithrandir](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir)

His head sounds like a myth, with an eye for why 
Endless, it says to meet but briefly so, 
standing for the very famous MA institute.

> **Mith** is the head, sounds like Myth, also i (eye) -> y (why) 
>  Supposedly Mit is pronounced similarly to Meet (Thanks Sid) 
>  MA (Massachusetts) Institute -> MIT, front of *Mit*hrandir

Then comes the first name of another puzzler, we all are very familiar with 
named after the prime of a time wheel with 
a horse god at his feet, whose kind really starts six places later.

> Next is **Rand**. 
>  First name of [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor), someone we are familiar with because they're #1 in Rep here. 
>  Named after the book series, Wheel of Time. 
>  Assuming horse -> Norse, Rand al'**Thor**, is 6 places into their name. (Apparently wrong) 
>  We're supposed to take the h of horse and add 6 to get an n for Norse, to make the **Thor**. (I prefer the first version)

At last, anger or annoy without end— 
its birth is half the death, where the dawn is equally four sided of 
any trio’s total member number.

> **Ir** is the end. 
>  Ire - e = Ir || Irk - k = Ir, endless anger/annoy. 
>  I (9) is half of R (18). And is 3^2 -- one day, from Rubio.

Bonus:

> There was a [dispute](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53992/babys-drink-mathematicians-think) about you posting their rhyme.